# How to Build Vue project with vue-cli 'npm run build' command that will contain relative reference in such tags as 'img', 'script' 'link' and others?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I need references to be look like this: ' **. /** static/img/i.png'.
Right now after building a project, it looks like this: ' **/** static/img/i.png'.

My problem:
When I try to open build project in browser, it dosn't show images. When I change the look of the link in debugger to: ' **. /** static/img/i.png' , everything works fine.

May be this problem can be solved through making some changes at webpack config file?

Comment: share your code so we can have a clue?

Comment: @Sag1v Sorry I didn't say. I use vue-cli. To get project I use standard command "npm run buid". I didn't make changes in webpack config.